# how to get the index of the QListWidgetItem in the itemDoubleClicked

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidgetitem

i have connected a function to a QListWidget's itemDoubleClicked. as far as i know it passes two arguments to the function (self, item). i want to get the index of this item so that i can access an item from another list which has the same indexes.

```
self.ResultList.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.switch_image)
```

the function

```
def switch_image(self, item):
    #temp = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem
    #t = temp.text()

    ''' what should be here '''

    # ind = item.index
    print(t)
```

Comment: use `print(self.ResultList.row(item))`

Comment: itemDoubleClicked just passes an argument: the item. The self is not because of the itemDoubleClicked but because it belongs to a class. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks, exactly what i was looking for.